# Windows 10, Monitor and Device deleted

Tags: windows-10, drivers, multiple-monitors

By mistake I pressed Fn+F7 (turn off monitor ) instead of Ctrl+F7.

No problem, right. Press on Fn+F7 again turned on laptop screen but not external monitor. After doing everything possible with cables, connecting and disconnecting, turning on and off, etc. I got to drivers. Checking driver I discovered in Events that device is 'deleted' ????

[image: Device Driver Event Log]

I tried reinstall driver, uninstall driver, delete driver files from HD, etc... In case of uninstalling and deleting drivers it comes back as 'Generic PnP Monitor' with same events history. Overwrite that driver with right one still has events history and 'deleted' status.

Now windows will not allow me to use this monitor.

How can I reverse deletion of device ? It can not be that hard, i guess. Microsoft put 'delete' functionality in, so they must have undelete, right. Why would you put 'delete' without ability to 'undelete' if you made a mistake ? Worst case scenario ( MS do not care if you made a mistake = reinstall everything from zero) is I have to go manually in Registry and delete some keys. Does anyone know where can I find those keys and delete them so I can have my monitor back ?

Laptop: ASUS ROG GL752VW

Monitor: Samsung S24D330, HDMI connection

PS: When I boot from Ubuntu Live, monitor is working just fine.

Thanks, 
Sasa Kajic

Comment: Sounds like your monitor is disabled. Try `Win`+`P`.

Comment: That was the very first thing I tried. "There is no device attached" :) Yet he see it in Device Manager and says it is "Deleted".

Comment: I don't think your driver is preventing the monitor from being active. Even a monitor using a generic driver can be enabled and display content. Have you looked at the display properties in Control Panel to see if the display is able to be activated there?

Comment: You can not activate it as "there is no device attached". Because it is deleted it "works as designed" (replay from MS). They give me some instructions how to try to "undelete" it. When I try all that, I will post it here if it works.